# iOS Alert Controller Whitescreen

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, webview, uialertcontroller

I am trying to bring up an UIAlert controller in which you choose how to export a PDF document in my app.

The app consists on a WebView on a ViewController, a single view app. 
The thing is, whenever one other controller is presented, it overlays a blank screen over the webview and never recovers the WebView. This happens in every version on iOS.

```
    UIAlertController *alertController = [UIAlertController
                                          alertControllerWithTitle:@"Share file" message:@"" preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];

    UIAlertAction *cancelAction = [UIAlertAction
                                   actionWithTitle:@"Cancel"
                                   style:UIAlertActionStyleCancel
                                   handler:^(UIAlertAction *action)
                                   {}];

    UIAlertAction *eMail = [UIAlertAction
                               actionWithTitle:@"Email"
                               style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault
                               handler:^(UIAlertAction *action)
                               {
                                   MFMailComposeViewController *picker = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];
                                   [picker setSubject:@""];
                                   [picker addAttachmentData:fileData mimeType:@"application/pdf" fileName:fileName];
                                   [picker setToRecipients:[NSArray array]];
                                   [picker setMessageBody:@"" isHTML:NO];
                                   [picker setMailComposeDelegate:self];
                                   [self presentViewController:picker animated:YES completion:nil];
                               }];

    UIAlertAction *docController = [UIAlertAction
                               actionWithTitle:@"Export"
                               style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault
                               handler:^(UIAlertAction *action){
                                   documentController.UTI = @"com.adobe.pdf";
                                   [documentController presentOpenInMenuFromRect:CGRectZero                                    inView:self.view animated:YES]; }];
    [alertController addAction:eMail];
    [alertController addAction:docController];
    [alertController addAction:cancelAction];
    [alertController setModalPresentationStyle:UIModalPresentationCurrentContext];
    [self presentViewController:alertController animated:YES completion:nil];
```

I need that after completing the action of sharing the file, the webview is presented on its last state

Comment: Why not use a standard `UIActivityViewController` to share the PDF file?

Comment: Since you using two different view controllers you should probably explicitly dismiss the alert controller before presenting `documentController`.

Comment: @rmaddy Hi, even using the UIActivityViewController lets my app with a blank screen after it finishes its actions.

Comment: @johnnieb I will add the dismiss, thanks for the tip. I'll let you know if it works

Comment: @johnnieb, didn't work. Still whitescreen when I come back to my app

Comment: I'd try wrapping the `documentController` presentation in a dispatch block after you explicitly dismiss, e.g., `dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{});`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @johnnieb stated, I wrapped the presentation in a dispatch block and worked like a charm!

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(),^{
  [self presentViewController:alertController animated:YES completion:^{}];
});
```

Thanks!

---

This works because we need to wait for the main queue to fully dismiss the previous view controller.